# Were Thingol and Thranduil related?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Are there any sources that can confirm or deny if they were kinsmen (family, not race)? After all, they both lived in Doriath and were similar in appearance.

Comment: Since Thranduil only had [two known relatives](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Thranduil#Genealogy) (his father and his son), establishing any further links is difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing to explicitly confirm or deny it. The only thing we know about Thranduil's parentage is that his father was a Sindarin elf of Doriath, named Oropher:

> [A]t last Thranduil established his realm in the north-east of the forest and delved there a fortress and great halls underground. Oropher was of Sindarin origin, and no doubt Thranduil his son was following the example of King Thingol long before, in Doriath; *[...]* [T]hey (and other similar adventurers forgotten in the legends or only briefly named) came from Doriath after its ruin and had no desire to leave Middle-earth
>
> <sup>*Unfinished Tales* Part 2: "The Second Age" Appendix B: "The Sindarin Princes of the Silvan Elves</sup>

But we know nothing about Oropher's familial connections.

All we know about Thingol is that he had two (known) brothers:

- Olwë, who went to Aman and became King of the Teleri
- Elmo, grandfather of Celeborn in some of Tolkien's later writings

There is no known connection between the two families, but any number of possible ways you could imagine one occurring.